# Factor Theorem with Polynomial Divison

Tags: polynomials

Factor theorem can get very complicated with a value of a $x^\text{high degree}$ and the constant being large, is there a simpler, more systematical way rather than guess and test? I find it really annoying...

If you don't get what I mean, consider $P(x) = 3x^3 - x -3$, this is a very easy example since the possible factors are $\pm 3,\pm 1,\pm\dfrac13$. But when numbers get large, especially the constant and the a term, it gets VERY COMPLICATED. I was wondering if there's a way around facing this time consumption, for instance, on a test...

Thanks!

Comment: Rational root theorem can give you a set of numbers to test.

Comment: But testing takes very long, if it's a polynomial from degree 5 to 1, then constant @Element118

Comment: I see what you mean, there may he too many numbers to test. If the high degree is odd, a solution can be found numerically, if that counts as finding a root.

Comment: But sometimes it's too complicated for that as well :/ Are you suggesting that there is no method around the factor and rational root theorem? @Element118

Comment: How can it be too complicated to find a root numerically?

Comment: It is very time consuming on tests, so I need to find a very efficient method, however, it may or may not get complicated depending on whether there are fractions. @Element118

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32651/discussion-between-element118-and-imagine-dragons).